# Loop through associative array in reverse

Tags: javascript

I'm using a javascript associative array (arr) and am using this method to loop through it.

```
for(var i in arr) {
    var value = arr[i];
    alert(i =") "+ value);
}
```

The problem is that the order of the items is important to me, and it needs to loop through from last to first, rather than first to last as it currently does.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Warning: this answer is ancient.**

If you're here for a quick fix, kindly refer to the [much better answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4956313/255756).

<sup>Original answer retained, because reasons. See comments.</sup>

---

Using a temporary array holding the keys in reverse order:

```
var keys = new Array();

for (var k in arr) {
    keys.unshift(k);
}

for (var c = keys.length, n = 0; n < c; n++) {
   alert(arr[keys[n]]);
}
```

Comment: @Urbycoz: but you're not guaranteed the same order in all browsers - see the other answers below.

Comment: @Urbycoz You might want to think about unaccepting this answer and accept Skilldricks's instead. I'd like to delete mine and I can't because you accepted it (my past me says "Thank you"). However, Skilldrick's is more accurate. Thanks.

Comment: Clever !? No way. this is utter garbage where the obvious simple answer would be the one below: reverted for loop.

Comment: ppl hate but this answer helps. Just keep in mind that associative array = js object.

Answer (score 47):

Four things:

1. JavaScript has arrays (integer-indexed [see comments below]) and objects (string-indexed). What you would call an associative array in another language is called an object in JS.
2. You [shouldn't use `for in` to loop through a JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays).
3. If you're looping through an object, use: [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
4. JavaScript doesn't guarantee the order of keys in an object. If you care about order, use an array instead.

If you're using a normal array, do this:

```
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //do something with arr[i]
}
```

Comment: +1, I deleted my answer in favour of this one.  Chrome is one browser that differs from the others with regards to enumeration order - http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164.

Comment: JS doesn't have any integer property names, even in arrays, so your first point is slightly misleading.

Comment: @Tim You're right, but to all (most) intents and purposes they are integer-indexed - the fact that they're strings under the hood is an implementation detail. Especially when explaining this to someone who talks about "associative arrays" in JavaScript it's useful to put stuff in terms they'd understand. Is that fair?

Comment: @Skilldrick: I think that's fair enough, I just wanted there to be a note to explain why `["foo"]["0"]` evaluates to "foo". I've upvoted already.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. It took me a couple of read-throughs to work out what that snippet was doing! I've put a note to look at the comments :)

Comment: @Skilldrick: Yeah, maybe that's too Resigian / clever-clever. `var a = ["foo"]; alert(a["0"]); // "foo"` might have been clearer.

Comment: @Urbycoz - no problem. Objects and arrays in JS can be a bit confusing when you're used to other languages.

Answer (score 3):

For a normal array, I would have done this:

```
var i = arr.length;
while (i--) {
    var value = arr[i];
    alert(i =") "+ value);
}
```

This is faster than a "for" loop.

http://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a

Comment: When you say this is faster than a `for` loop, you mean to say that it's faster when doing a reverse iteration specifically?

Comment: `for in` for an array as in the OP's example - in some browsers it was also faster than the negative for loop - but I have not tested this in some time (note the 5 year old post)

Comment: Note that the negative iteration in javascript (this or the for) gives the parser a chance to enhance performance given the length is known prior - so it MIGHT in-line or otherwise optimize that.  There is a PHD dissertation somewhere out there re: parsed languages have the potential to exceed compiled languages performance such as C, C++ etc. but the reference escapes me that has to do with this factor.

Comment: Thanks for the info, would be a great read if you did happen to come across it again :)

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers you can now use `Object.keys` to get your array of properties and step through it in reverse order, allowing you to skip the preliminary key collection loop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```
var keys = Object.keys(subject);
for (var i = keys.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var k = keys[i],
        v = subject[k];
    console.log(k+":",v);
}
```

Comment: OP talks about arrays not objects/maps. This answer does not add anything compared to `Skilldrick'es`.

Comment: @RickyA: 
OP does in fact talk about iterating an Object. Skilldrick's response indicates an understanding that OP is referring to an Object via incorrect terminology, but proceeds to respond as if the question were about iterating an Array.