# How do I reverse() an associative array (object)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop through associative array in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956256/loop-through-associative-array-in-reverse)

I have a key-value pair javascript object.
How do I reverse() it? or loop it starting from the bottom.
jQuery available.

Comment: 1 option is to convert object to array and use JS reverse function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard specification or guarantee of determining the order of properties in a Javascript object. Most browsers go from what was added first to last, but as [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)
describes, Chrome and Opera do not.

If order is important to you, then you must use an array, or have an array that lists the order in which the properties should be accessed when looping (from either direction).